# Could not fin or load main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc

Tags: java, salesforce, wsdl

I'm trying to generate a salesforce.jar file from the salesforce.wsdl file from a partner.

We are trying to use version 57.0.0 from Salesforce so I downloaded force-wsc-57.0.0.jar. Also when trying to generate the file, I get an error regarding to ST4, so I downloaded ST4-4.3.4.jar too.

Now when I run the command:

> java -cp force-wsc-57.0.0.jar,ST4-4.3.4.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc partner.wsdl partner.jar

I always get the error "Could not find or load main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc". I saw that this package exists inside force-wsc-57.0.0.jar so it should be working.

I'm using java8, I put everything on a folder together, the jars and the wsdl file. I run the command prompt from this route so I don't need to add the path to the jars files or anything.

Comment: Are you trying to run a package? Shouldn't you be running a class, instead?

Comment: Hi @FedericoklezCulloca, yes wsdlc is a class inside the package com.sforce.ws.tools

Comment: According to the documentation `-cp` expects a semicolon-separated list, not a comma-separated one. Try like this: `java -cp "force-wsc-57.0.0.jar;ST4-4.3.4.jar" com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc partner.wsdl partner.jar`

Comment: Hi again @FedericoklezCulloca, thanks for the answer. I tried this but stil get the same error, could not find the main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.

Comment: There are instructions for running the generator here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_java_stubs.htm

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was all together.

As Federico Klez Culloca said, must be a semicolon-separated list. Also needs to add some jars like ST4.

At the end, the problem was that you need to call command prompt from the java\bin folder. So you need to place the root inside this bin folder and then launch this command with all the complete paths to the jars, wsdl and the jar you want to generate.